# Determining Min and Max elevation in Python using GDAL?

Tags: python, gdal, dem, elevation, zonal-statistics

I have a DEM file and shapefile of specific area, and I want to 
Create a module in Python that writes name of each area which is shown in the picture, with the greatest differences in altitude on the territory (min-max range of the altitude).

I also have to create a new layer containing the shape of these areas, together with all its original attributes.

I have GDAL and ArcPy libraries.

Could you please help me determine what I should do?

Comment: What GIS library for Python are you using?

Comment: i am using gdal library.

Comment: There's [some sample code on the GDAL/OGR cookbook](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html#calculate-zonal-statistics). If I understand you right, I think you're asking about 'zonal statistics'.

Comment: yes this is about zonal statistics.

Comment: Have you tried the sample code suggested by @StevenKay? If so, and if you are still stuck, then include a code snippet to show what you tried.

Comment: I think saying "i want to Create a module in Python" and then including no evidence of a code start suggests that you have mistaken us for a code writing service.  We are happy to help people with their clearly described code snippets but not to take short descriptions of required code and do it for them.

Answer (score 2):

If it doesn't have to be Python, just use R, it's very well suited for this with high-level tools.

Pseudo-session (requires `rgdal` installed as well for read/write shapefile):

```
library(raster)
s <- shapefile("file.shp")
d <- raster("dem.whatever")
s$demmin <- extract(d, s, fun = min, na.rm = TRUE)
s$demmax <- extract(d, s, fun = max, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Write it back out

```
shapefile(s, "file_minmax.shp")
```

Answer (score 1):

As it was pointed out by **Steven Kay**, there's some [sample code](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html#calculate-zonal-statistics) on the **GDAL/OGR** cookbook about 'zonal statistics', so it's some extensive when it is compared with the **mdsumner**'s R code. I know that R power can be used in Python by using the **rpy** and **rpy2** python modules. After install them, I tried out next code in PyQGIS environment:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

import rpy2.robjects as robjects
import os

r = robjects.r

mapcanvas = iface.mapCanvas()
layers = mapcanvas.layers()

vp = layers[0].dataProvider()
vpath_tmp = vp.dataSourceUri().split('|')
vpath = vpath_tmp[0]

rp = layers[1].dataProvider()
rpath = rp.dataSourceUri()

vroot, vfile = os.path.split(vpath)
rroot, rfile = os.path.split(rpath)

r.setwd(vroot)

r.library('raster')

arg1 = 's <- shapefile(' + "\"" + vfile + "\"" + ')'
arg2 = 'd <- raster(' + "\"" + rfile + "\"" + ')'

r(arg1)
r(arg2)

print "Wait..."

demmin = r('s$demmin <- extract(d, s, fun = min, na.rm = TRUE)')
demmax = r('s$demmax <- extract(d, s, fun = max, na.rm = TRUE)')

fields = [ QgsField('min', QVariant.Double), QgsField('max', QVariant.Double) ]
vp.addAttributes( fields )
layers[0].updateFields()

idx1 = layers[0].fieldNameIndex('min')
idx2 = layers[0].fieldNameIndex('max')

n = len(demmin)

for i in range(n):
    new_values = { idx1 : demmin[i], idx2 : demmax[i] }
    vp.changeAttributeValues( {i:new_values} )

print "Done!"
```

with the polygon vector layer and dem raster of next image:

[image]

After running the code at the Python Console of QGIS, two new fields (min and max) were incorporated to attributes table of vector layer and preserved its original attributes; as it can be observed at next image:

[image]

It worked for me.